# Jquery DataTable serverside rendering and pagination error in front end

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using `php` and this query `select * from table` and the result I want to show in `jquery` `datatable` in server side processing means I want to use `jquery` `datatable`'s own `ajax` method. I have all total 58 rows. So by default I should have 6 page. 10 rows per page. Data is coming and is shown in the table. but with wrong pagination.

Actually it shows all 58 rows in the first page and also showing 6 pagination buttons. If I click on anything nothing is working. searching and sorting not working.

I am not pasting the `sql` code here but the I am pasting the procedural code of `php` here.

`php` code:

```
require_once("logic/LogsDataLogic.php");

$ldl = new LogsDataLogic();
$data = $ldl->getDataByFromDateToDate();

$arr = [
    "draw" => $_POST["draw"],
    "recordsTotal" => count($data),
    "recordsFiltered" => count($data),
    "data" => $data
];

echo json_encode($arr);
```

`jquery` code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
            $('#logs_table').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '../app/getData.php',
                    type: "POST"
                }
            } );
    });
```

`html` code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

                                <table class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="logs_table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>User ID</th>
                                            <th>Login Time</th>
                                            <th>IP</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>User ID</th>
                                            <th>Login Time</th>
                                            <th>IP</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
<!-- end here -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I have attached an image of the final result.[Table Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT7GF.jpg)

Comment: I think you missed the table structure that is why datatable not working.. please check console..may helps you..

Comment: I have added everything here. You can see that but no error in console

Answer (score 1):

**Sol 1:**

if you don't want pagination from the server just set **"serverSide": false,**
this will bring all your record ie 58 at one go but pagination will work.

**Sol 2:**

if you want pagination from server-side means to fetch only 10 records each time follow these steps

you have added "serverSide": true, so when you look into console along with other parameters **some additional parameters are passed**. 
which you need to handle in your server-side query with **limit 20,10**

refer:  https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

eg:

```
draw:4
columns[0][data]:0
start:20
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

**Explanation:**

*when you set serverSide as false*

datatable gets all records from the server(in your case 58) and paginates in UI as suggested(10 rec each page) 
so when you change page no ajax call is fired

*when you set serverSide as true*

Datable get only first 10 records and when you change page ajax call is fired to get another set of 10 records.
Datatable adds some parameters along with request and expects you to handle that in server-side 
eg: first record and total no of record per set and total no of record available

SO for each request start and length is passed to get no of records from which index

in response datable expect 
"draw":2,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57 along with data

draw is a unique key which you can use from request 
recordsTotal is no of record: for this, you need additional query to get a count of all records

Refer to [this post](https://ashishontech.xyz/server-side-pagination-jquery-datatable/) for more detail with live demo and sample code.

Comment: let I want to get rows from 11 to 20. then in sql I should write "select * from table limit 11,10".. Now question is how would I get the totalnoofRows for pagination? Would I use two queries. In 1st query totalnoofRows and in 2nd row limit

Comment: To get the totalRecords you need to do a count on the dataset _before_ you do the paging, kind of like your `count($data)`

Comment: my whole dataset size is 58 but when I load the first page means 0 to 10 then my dataset size is 10 then how would I get 58? second query or anything?

Comment: I want sol 2 then what would I do?